# How to download and install old version of Firefox

Tags: firefox, installation, file-download

I'm trying to install an old version of Firefox from the following URL:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/16.0/

but it's a big list of files, I can't find an install file..

How do I download these files and install on windows machine?

Comment: Go to Win32. Then select your language, assuming you're American then it'll be En-US.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows is in the win32 directory. Then you pick your localization. Examples: en_US is US English; en_UK is UK English; es is Espanol or Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

Find the below path

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/16.0/win32/en-US/

double click the exe file then install firefox